Kubernetes CoreDNS pod has "I/O Timeout" When attempting to reach DNS server
I am running a local 4-node Kubernetes cluster (k8s v1.30.2) with Calico v3.28.0 as my CNI. All kube-system pods are up and running, but DNS resolution does not work correctly. Attempting to nslookup kubernetes.default from a debug pod returns NXDOMAIN. The coreDNS pod logs reveal the following errors.
[ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 zk-hs. A: read udp 10.0.30.9:35093->10.52.2.156:53: i/o timeout
[ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 zk-hs. AAAA: read udp 10.0.30.9:37091->172.17.22.206:53: i/o timeout
[ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 zk-hs. A: read udp 10.0.30.9:50550->172.17.22.206:53: i/o timeout
[ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 zk-hs. AAAA: read udp 10.0.30.9:54820->10.8.130.181:53: i/o timeout
[ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 zk-hs. A: read udp 10.0.30.9:48084->10.8.130.181:53: i/o timeout

The destination IP addresses (10.52.2.156, 172.17.22.206, 10.8.130.181) are the DNS servers listed in my /etc/resolv.conf. Evidently, the coreDNS pod is unable to connect to the DNS servers. I am not sure what the cause of this is. calicoctl node status reports no network errors.
Calico process is running.
IPv4 BGP status
+---------------+-------------------+-------+------------+-------------+
| PEER ADDRESS  |     PEER TYPE     | STATE |   SINCE    |    INFO     |
+---------------+-------------------+-------+------------+-------------+
| 10.129.37.141 | node-to-node mesh | up    | 2024-07-03 | Established |
| 10.129.37.219 | node-to-node mesh | up    | 2024-07-04 | Established |
| 10.52.133.42  | node-to-node mesh | up    | 2024-07-04 | Established |
+---------------+-------------------+-------+------------+-------------+

IPv6 BGP status
No IPv6 peers found.


I have run iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT && iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT && iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT && iptables -F and restarted the coreDNS pods as suggested in this github issue, with no results. I have tried disabling firewalld on all nodes, which also failed to fix the issue.
How should I go about debugging this issue? Thanks.
